# Is the author of the article below right? To cast two (6) of the Maxwell equations into a QM wavefunction?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wavefunction, quantum-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations

Look at this flow chart:
[image]
It's taken from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169) article (from the archives of Cornell University), in which this is claimed:

> James Clerk Maxwell unknowingly discovered a correct relativistic, quantum theory for the light quantum, forty-three years before Einstein postulated the photon"s existence. In this theory, the usual Maxwell field is the quantum wave function for a single photon.

Is this correct? I know the Maxwell equations are used in quantizing the e.m. field but I always thought a photon wavefunction had two components afterward. Well, actually four, but this can be reduced to two by [gauge fixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_fixing).In the flow diagram, two of the Maxwell equations are obtained, but why writing them as a wavefunction?
So what am I supposed to think of this article? Somehow I think there is something done wrong. But what? For example, why is a wavefunction connected with the two Maxwell equations (at least, I think that symbol implies a wavefunction)? But is this the same one as in the second box? And on top of that, what does the title of the article mean: **The Maxwell wave function of the photon**
Is he right in doing this?

Comment: The electromagnetic field in Maxwell's equations is not quantised.

Comment: @StudyStudy I don't understand why that question showed up. But I edited (as I did the question).

Comment: @StudyStudy Why can't someone unknowingly discover something? If I close my eyes I can unknowingly discover everything that's visible to others.

Comment: On reflection about the quote.  I have discovered that I am wrong :) apologies, best of luck with your question.

Comment: Unknowingly?:) Alright! Thanks.

Comment: Surely Max Planck proposed light quanta before Einstein expanded on the concept. Maxwell most definitely did not propose any kind of electromagnetic quantization, he worked fully in a wave-based paradigm. In that era, even the quantization of matter (i.e., atoms) was treated with grave suspicion.

Comment: @bemjanim Then why does he cast he Maxwell equations (actually two of them) in a wavefunction?

Comment: I don't know, but Maxwell's equations as he discovered them don't predict photons, they predict a classical wave model of light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I am no historian, Maxwell did not come up with a "relativistic,quantum" theory for light.

1. Maxwell's equations put forth a classical wave picture of EM fields. Light was though to be such an EM field. After Huygens and Young, corpuscular theory was dropped anyways.
2. The concept of quantization, let alone photon wasn't arrived at yet.
3. The only insight that the Maxwells equation had before their time, in this context, was their manifest Lorentz covarinace even before special relativity was discovered.
4. The quantities calculated from the Maxwell's equations are physical fields in stark contrast to the wavefunction of a photon.
5. There is no such thing as relativistic QM-only quantum field theory. Combining relativity with quantum mechanics requires the introduction of an infinity of particles, fields and their quantization,  etc--a lot of technology that wasn't present in Maxwell's times.
6. The quantum behaviour of light is not at all described by the Maxwell's equations-in fact they fail at small scale/ high energies and get replaced by the QED formulation.

Comment: But Maxwell's equations ARE used in the formulation of the photon's wavefunction. Though QFT starts with Lagrangian densities.

Comment: yes..in the action but thats not what the equations give us-they give us $E$ and $B$-end of story. That they can be used to make quantum wavefunctions is a whole other thing not creditable to Maxwell.